# Можно ли в timestamp witchout time zone записать нулевое время и как?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Какое значение нужно передать в `timestamp witchout time zone` поле, что бы время установилось в `0000-00-00 00:00:00`?

Comment: В mssql я делал прямую конвертацию `cast( (cast x_date as int)   as datetime)`, Может в postgresql так тоже можно кастить. Приходилось делать округление, т.к. по умолчанию 0,6 превращается в 1.  1-означает день, 0.5-это 12 часов. Возможно округление решит эту проблему (кастить в дробное-округлить-кастить в датувремя). Если нет - копать ф-ции даты времени.

Comment: Если прямая конструкция `cast('0000-00-00 00:00:00' as datetime)` даёт ошибку, то "нулевого" времени нету у postgre. выкручивайтесь через *null*, минимальное и/или максимальное время (ввиду того что null плохо индексируется).

Comment: ну к datetime не получится , а к timestamp не кастуется с криком (значение поля типа date/time вне диапазона), а 1970-01-01 00:00:00 кастуется нормально.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хотя `postgresql` для `timestamp` умеет хранить даты от 4713 года до нашей эры до глубокого будущего, используются правила григорианского календаря, в котором [года 0 нет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4). После -1 до нашей эры был сразу 1 год нашей эры.

Поэтому `timestamp` с нулевым годом в `postgresql` быть не может.